# KDE's run command is broken when using multiple monitors

Tags: ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

When running *run command* (shortcut or from desktop menu) it only works on one monitor. On all other monitors no window is shown (it is working, "just" window position seems to be broken, when I don't see suggestions it is kinda useless).

In its options are just items which use for searching, nothing related to monitors or window placement. Any ideas how to fix this annoyance?

I am using Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far only solution I found out is to restart the `krunner` when "run command" is broken.

I have a following script which I usually run right after launch:

```
killall krunner
krunner > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```